# DateTime.parse doesn't take seconds or offset

Tags: datetime

DateTime.parse() won't take seconds or offsets, at least not in the US.  The format from the documention in [DateTime.methods()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) is the only one I can find that works:

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```

I haven't found documentation stating this, and in some places I've gotten error messages suggesting that I need to use "mm/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss:nnnZ+HH.mm", which I have tried extensively without success.  Some other users on this forum seem to have struggled with the same issue.

I have seen the explanations that datetime.parse() expects the date in the local timezone format, but wasn't aware that the US timezones don't use seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to work around the limitations with `DateTime.parse()` is to use JSON deserialization. It will take an ISO 8601 formatted date time.

The will give you millisecond resolution on the resulting DateTime.

E.g.

```
// Note the surrounding double quotes to make this valid JSON!
string s = '"2011-10-14T11:46:13.172Z"';
Datetime dt = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize(s,DateTime.class);
system.debug(dt);
system.assertEquals(13, dt.second());
system.assertEquals(172, dt.millisecond());
```